# Quiz app - comparing values from inputs and JSON after button click

Tags: json, angularjs

I wanted to make simple quiz app.
In my JSON file I have question with answers and points for an answer.
I want to list questions, gives text inputs for user to fulfill and a button to check answers. After clicking button I will show result and mark with green or red questions which were answered correct or incorrect.

I am able to list questions but I do not know how after clicking button I could go through all inputs and do all operations: (check them with corresponding answers from JSON file, add points, mark fields).

My JSON file is:

```
[
{
    "id": 1, 
    "question": "How much is it: 2+2",
    "answer": ["4", "four"], 
    "points": 2
},
{
    "id": 2, 
    "question": "How much is it: 2*2",
    "answer": ["4", "four"], 
    "points": 3
},
{
    "id": 3, 
    "question": "How much is it: 2+2*2",
    "answer": ["6", "six"], 
    "points": 4
}]
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>What are Your answers? </h3>
      <form>
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in answers">
                <label>Question (Id: {{item.id}}): {{item.question}}</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="{{item.id}}" id="{{item.id}}">
            </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="calculatePoints()">Check</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Number of points which You have:</h3>        
      <span>{{e}}</span>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.calculatePoints = function() {


};
```

Comment: Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms and understand how you can bind form input values to model values using ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to give `ng-model` to input

secondly you can pass answer element and answer to the `calculatepionts` function

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.currentAnswer" 
 name="{{item.id}}" id="{{item.id}}">
```

sending the question object and answer to the calculate function

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
ng-click="calculatePoints(item,item.currentAnswer)">Check</button>
```

Now you can compare the answer with the orignal one in `calculatePoints`()

Comment: sounds good! 
How can I play with it now?
$scope.calculatePoints = function(item, inputAnswer) {
   if(item.answer === inputAnswer) {
    alert('ok');
   }

  };

gives error item is not declare? How should I declare it.
How I will be able to tell angular to let's say add class to input if answer is correct?

Comment: are you passing the item from view? ng-click="calculatePoints(item,item.currentAnswer)"

Comment: Yes I am passing it - I have following code as well
$http.get('js/quiz.json').success (function(data){
   $scope.answers = data;
  }); 

  $scope.calculatePoints = function(item, inputAnswer) {
   if(item.answer === inputAnswer) {
    alert('ok');
   }

  };